# How to push an input item to an empty array and have it output to h1 tag using the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a few input text boxes one been used to add items to an array. However, I'm able to get items to show up in the DOM that I declared to show the results but the items aren't being added to the array. I've created an empty array to accept the values from the input text box on the HTML page. Please help me with the push method.

```
<body>
<script>
function groceries() {
let grocery = [];    
const x = document.querySelector(".add").value; 
let count = grocery;
grocery = x;
console.log(count);
console.log(grocery);

document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = grocery;
 return count;
```

}

```
</script>

<h1 class="result">RESULTS</h1>

<div class="center">
<label for="">Date Time</label><br>
<input type="datetime" name="" id=""><br>

<!--Code below is for search-->
<label for="search">Search</label><br>
<input class="search" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" id=""><br>

<!--//This line will add items to the grocery list, array.-->
<label for="grocery">Enter groceries</label><br>
<input class="add" type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Groceries" id=""><br>

<!--This line removes item from the grocery list/ array.-->
<label for="grocery">Remove groceries</label><br>
<input class="remove" type="text" name="" placeholder="Remove Groceries" id=""><br><br>

<!-- Button to run the function above starting at line 13-->
<button type ="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="groceries()" >Enter grocery</button>
```

Comment: Please indent your code - hard to follow as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the array is being reset to empty every time the function is called.
Storing the array outside of the func will stop it from being reset. You also need to push the item into the array.

```
            let grocery = [];    

            function groceries() {
                const x = document.querySelector(".add").value; 
                grocery.push(x)
                document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = grocery;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response and you are correct. Once I stored the array outside and push it into X it worked.